# How do I check if input is a number in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, input, numbers

I have a Python script which converts a decimal number into a binary one and this obviously uses their input.

I would like to have the script validate that the input is a number and not anything else which will stop the script.

I have tried an if/else statement but I don't really know how to go about it. I have tried `if decimal.isint():` and `if decimal.isalpha():` but they just throw up errors when I enter a string.

```
print("Welcome to the Decimal to Binary converter!")
while True:
    print("Type a decimal number you wish to convert:")
    decimal = int(input())
    if decimal.isint():
        binary = bin(decimal)[2:]
        print(binary)
    else:
        print("Please enter a number.")
```

Without the if/else statement, the code works just fine and does its job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `int()` call succeeded, `decimal` is **already** a number. You can only call `.isdigit()` (the correct name) on a string:

```
decimal = input()
if decimal.isdigit():
    decimal = int(decimal)
```

The alternative is to use exception handling; if a `ValueError` is thrown, the input was not a number:

```
while True:
    print("Type a decimal number you wish to convert:")
    try:
        decimal = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        continue

    binary = bin(decimal)[2:]
```

Instead of using the `bin()` function and removing the starting `0b`, you could also use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format), using the `'b'` format, to format an integer as a binary string, without the leading text:

```
>>> format(10, 'b')
'1010'
```

The `format()` function makes it easy to add leading zeros:

```
>>> format(10, '08b')
'00001010'
```

Comment: In Python 2.x, you wouldn't need to call `isdigit`, infact, that would throw an error

Comment: @elssar: this is clearly not Python 2. In Python 2, you'd use `raw_input()` in this case.

Comment: well yes, but I thought it should be worth mentioning that in the answer. In my haste I forgot to mention that bit :/