# Prompting the user for an int, not a string, until they do even if it's a negative number

Tags: python-3.6

I'm writing a program and it asks the user to input a number, I need to make sure that that number is and actual number not a string. That number can be positive or negative. I've tried using .isnumerical() and .isdigit() but they won't except negative numbers.

```
lowest_num = input("What would you like the lowest possible number to be?")
while lowest_num.isdigit() is not True:
    lowest_num = (input("Please only enter a number : ")).lower()
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if input is a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095244/how-do-i-check-if-input-is-a-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lowest_num = int(input("What would you like the lowest possible number to be?"))` should do it

Alright, try this:

```
number_not_entered = True
num = 0 
while number_not_entered:
  try: 
    num = int(input("enter num"))
    number_not_entered = False
  except ValueError:
    print("please try again")
```

Note that catching all exceptions is generally a bad practice.

Comment: This will not prompt the user for a int until they do, this will just throw up an error and end the program.

Comment: it wasn't in your original question, do you think you can update it?

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `isnan()` function from `numpy` library. First import `numpy` and then use `numpy.isnan(a number)`

Comment: I tried to import numpy but it told me there wasn't a module named that.FYI I'm using Pycharm 2017.3, don't know if that matters.